# Flutter web, Hive: browser shows blank page when refreshed

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-hive

I've been working on a Flutter web app and I've implemented Hive in it to store some data locally. But when I reload one of the pages that fetches the data from a hive box using the browser's reload button, it crashes and shows

> HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 34. Did you forget to register an adapter?

I know for sure I've registered all the adapters:

```
  void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  Hive.registerAdapter<UserModel>(UserModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<UserModel>('user_model');

  Hive.registerAdapter<DocModel>(DocModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<DocModel>('doc_model');

  Hive.registerAdapter<AuthorModel>(AuthorModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<AuthorModel>('author_model');

  Hive.registerAdapter<TopicModel>(TopicModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<TopicModel>('topic_model');

  Hive.registerAdapter<TypeModel>(TypeModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<TypeModel>('type_model');

  runApp(const MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

And I've also followed the rest of the steps to create a box. This is one of them:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'topic_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class TopicModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String? name;
  @HiveField(1)
  String? code;
  @HiveField(2)
  List<String>? subTopic;
  TopicModel({this.name, this.code, this.subTopic});
  TopicModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> response, List<String> subtype) {
    name = response['name'];
    code = response['code'];
    subTopic = subtype;
  }
}
```

This is the .g.dart file for that particular box:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'topic_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class TopicModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<TopicModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 3;

  @override
  TopicModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return TopicModel(
      name: fields[0] as String?,
      code: fields[1] as String?,
      subTopic: (fields[2] as List?)?.cast<String>(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, TopicModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.code)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.subTopic);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is TopicModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Yes, I have given unique typeId for all the boxes. And storing the data and fetching it works correctly the first time when I run the app on chrome. But whenever I reload the page, it gets stuck in a white screen and a few seconds later the error I mentioned earlier gets thrown. But when I checked IndexedDb of that page, the data is still there which means it's not getting deleted. So what is problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem with my application too, did you find any solutions?